# Verilog - Port Size Does Not Match Connection Size

Tags: port, verilog, modelsim

Using ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.4a. Wrote a module for a 1-4 demux. Wrote a test bench for that module. Compiles fine. When trying to simulate, I get the following errors:

> # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v(42): [PCDPC] - Port size (1) does not match connection size (4) for port 'in'. The port definition is at: D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v(1).
>   #    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb_demux/DA0 File: D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v
>   # ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-3053) D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v(42): Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'out'.
>   #    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb_demux/DA0 File: D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v
>   # ** Warning: (vsim-3015) D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v(42): [PCDPC] - Port size (4) does not match connection size (1) for port 'out'. The port definition is at: D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v(1).
>   #    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb_demux/DA0 File: D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab3_3.v

Code is:

```
module demux(input in, input[1:0] S, output reg[3:0] out);


always @(in or S)
begin
     case(S)
    2'b00: begin
        out[0] = in;
        out[1] = 0;
        out[2] = 0;
        out[3] = 0;
        end
    2'b01: begin
        out[0] = 0;
        out[1] = in;
        out[2] = 0;
        out[3] = 0;
        end
    2'b10: begin
        out[0] = 0;
        out[1] = 0;
        out[2] = in;
        out[3] = 0;
        end
    2'b11: begin
        out[0] = 0;
        out[1] = 0;
        out[2] = 0;
        out[3] = in;
        end
     endcase
end

endmodule   


module tb_demux;
wire[3:0] out;
reg[1:0] S;
reg in;

demux DA0(out, S, in);

initial
begin

    S = 2'b00; in = 0;
    #100 S = 2'b01; in = 1;
    #100 S = 2'b10; in = 0;
    #100 S = 2'b11; in = 1;
end

initial #400 $stop;

initial $monitor("Select = %b, In = %b, Out = %b", S, in, out);
endmodule
```

Cannot seem to make this work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiation of the design has not been done properly from the testbench.
Ports in the design are incorrectly mapped to the testbench.

Change the instantiation of the design from the testbench to following:

```
demux DA0(in,s,out);
```

**It is always better to instantiate design using name rather than order in verilog to avoid these kinds of port mismatches.**

Comment: What do you mean using name rather than order?

Comment: GO through this [link](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00027.htm) to understand the different instantiations in verilog:

Comment: Connect by name: `demux DA0( .in(in), .S(s), .out(out) );` port order does not matter. Another equivalent example: `demux DA0( .out(out), .in(in), .S(s) );`

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I was apparently feeding the variables into the test bench in the wrong order.

The proper line is:

```
demux DA0(in, S, out);
```

So the variables are the same order as they are declared in the module:

```
module demux(input in, input[1:0] S, output reg[3:0] out);
```

Comment: Yes, but don't ever use order; always always use name. Order is too error prone, as your example has demonstrated.